# Modular form in M_2 (11) that only vanishes at the cusp 0

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Hi, I've been thinking about this questions:

Is there a modular form in $M_2 (\Gamma_0(11))$ which only vanishes at the cusp 0? If so how can we find it?

Edit: There was another question which I removed.

Comment: Yes, take a suitable linear combination of the Eisenstein form with the cuspform $\eta(q)^2 \eta(q^{11})^2$.

Comment: This cuspform vanishes at 0, does the Eisenstein form vanish at 0 as well? 
Also, how do I make sure the linear combination does not vanish anywhere else on the upper half plane?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you asked for no other zeros at all
(though come to think of it what I wrote doesn't make sense anyway
for the reason you suggest).  OK, let's try again: there is no
such form $\phi$, because if it existed then $\phi / (\eta(q)^2 \eta(q^{11}))^2$
would be a function on degree 1 on $X_0(11)$ [pole at the cusp $\infty$,
zero at the cusp $0$], which is impossible because $X_0(11)$ is known
to have genus 1.


Comment: Alternatively, the space of cusp forms has codimension one, and the Atkin-Lehner involution switches the two cusps. Thus, any form must either vanish at both cusps or vanish at neither.

Comment: @Nadim : What do you mean exactly by vanishing ? Do you mean that there is no constant term in the Fourier expansion (at the cusp 0), or do you mean vanishing as a differential form on $X_0(11)$ ? This is not the same, for example the cusp form $\eta(q)^2 \eta(q^11)^2 \frac{dq}{q}$ doesn't vanish anywhere as a differential form.

Comment: @Noam: Very nice argument, thanks!
@Kevin: Did you mean that the existence of such a form f vanishing only at 0 implies the existence of a form vanishing only at infinity, by applying the Atkin-Lehner involution? This would also lead to a contradiction, but I'm not sure if that's what you meant. Thanks for the idea!
@François: I meant no constant term in the Fourier expansion at 0. 